# TabLayout with custom icon doesn't change icon on start

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I have TabLayout and ViewPager in my layout, pretty standart.
And I'm using custom views for my tabs.
In Activity onCreate method I call:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
setupViewPager(binding.viewpager);
binding.tabs.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewpager);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.tab).setText(R.string.tab_home)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.tab_home_icon).setTag(HOME_TAG); 
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(R.layout.tab).setText(R.string.tab_games)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.tab_games_icon).setTag(GAMES_TAG);
```

And here is how mu drawables look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_home_active" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_home" />
</selector>
```

I want to show orange icon, if tab is selected and grey otherwise.
And everything works fine except for very beginning. If I navigate from tab to tab once - everything is fine:

[image]

[image]

But when activity just started - Home tab is not "selected":

[image]

I've already tried to select tab pragmatically - didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to select tab programmatically in `onResume()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer:

```
binding.tabs.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
```

or even

```
int selectedTabPosition = binding.tabs.getSelectedTabPosition();
binding.tabs.getTabAt(selectedTabPosition).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
```

It was not on purpose, I just dig a little in android sources.

Comment: Answering your own question is no problem as long as it is a solution. You can even accept it. Because it can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

Viewpage.setcurrentItem(0) at the end

Comment: In this case I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` on `tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView` - there are no tabs.